# E: Type 'echo' is not known mono-xmarin.list issue

Tags: 15.04

can anyone help me with this issue. I have been using Ubuntu for years and never encountered a problem until now. I cannot update because of this error:

```
E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Comment: I tried that link for answers and none of them work

Comment: What does the second line of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in line 2 of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

You can fix it manually, or just delete this file by:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what happened.  The echo line somehow was pasted directly into your list file.  Copy and paste the following to a terminal window to correct it.

`sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: After running sudo apt - get update i get this error nowE: Type 'deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read

Comment: @ChristianDoiron just fixed my answer for you.